# Error parsing application.xml when trying to publish a WebLogic 12.2.1 application

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic12c

I have Java web application that runs on WebLogic 12.2.1.  I've never had any trouble publishing to run locally - until now.

Now I always get the following error:

weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error parsing META-INF/application.xml

The application.xml file itself seems fine, and it definitely hasn't changed.  I can't figure out what the issue is.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look and share the log and the complete stack trace written when the exception is raised. This will help to find if there is an issue with the application.xml file

Comment: Thanks - you've definitely got me a bit further.

I looked in the log files - and came up with this error in particular...

Failed to create App/Comp MBeans for AppDeploymentMBean.

I believe the AppDeploymentMBean resides in a jar file in my Weblogic server director.

The only thing is I'm not sure why it can't see that class, since I would think all Weblogic libraries should be visible since I'm running on a Weblogic server.  If I try to add the .jar file manually - I still get the same error.

Comment: ...and I've checked the WebLogic System Libraries - the jar file that that bean resides in - wls-api.jar - is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the steer.  It all has to do with replacing every instance of

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/

with

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/

in your xml files such as application.xml and weblogic.xml.